# Package not working on Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, package

I have created a package and installed in different dev env it is working fine but when i installed the same package on a sandbox it getting error. Not able to understand why it getting error i tried installing 3 times. Do anybody have any idea.

Comment: Can you share the error message in your question please.

Comment: their is no error message the thing is that some features are not working.

Comment: Can you elaborate on which features and what your expectations are? You will stand a much better chance of getting some great answers if you give a bit more info. :)